# geckodriver executable needs to be in path

Tags: python

I have read previous questions asked on this topic and tried to follow the suggestions but I continue to get errors. On terminal, I ran

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/Conger/Documents/geckodriver-0.8.0-OSX
```

I also tried

```
    export PATH=$PATH:/Users/Conger/Documents/geckodriver
```

When I run the following Python code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities


firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
firefox_capabilities['binary'] = '/Users/Conger/Documents/Firefox.app'

driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities)
```

I still get the following error

```
Python - testwebscrap.py:8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Conger/Documents/Python/Crash_Course/testwebscrap.py", line 11, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities)
  File "/Users/Conger/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 135, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Users/Conger/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 71, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH. 

Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.firefox.service.Service object at 0x1006df6d0>> ignored
[Finished in 0.194s]
```

Comment: managed to figure this out! Instead of creating a new path, I just added the geckodriver file into the Path listed in my bash_profile. Worked immediately!

Answer (score 44):

you may downgrade your selenium by

**pip install selenium==2.53.6**

This has solved my issue

Comment: Is there a better alternative than downgrading?

Comment: Worked, but  why?

Comment: The ubuntu version are not been upgraded according to the python packages. So we can downgrade selenium or may add the gekodriver in the path and tell the path

Answer (score 11):

On mac:

```
brew install geckodriver
```

Homebrew is the most popular package manager for Mac OS X, you will need install XCode on your mac and it will be then accesible from your terminal.

You can follow [this tutorial](https://www.howtogeek.com/211541/homebrew-for-os-x-easily-installs-desktop-apps-and-terminal-utilities/) if required

Answer (score 10):

First we know that gekodriver is the driver engine of Firefox,and we know that
      `driver.Firefox()` is used to open Firefox browser, and it will call the gekodriver engine ,so we need to give the gekodirver a executable permission.
so  we download the latest gekodriver uncompress the tar packge ,and put gekodriver at the `/usr/bin/`
ok,that's my answer and i have tested.

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Pretty neat answer.

Answer (score 7):

I just downloaded the latest version **geckodriver** (I have win7) from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)  and added that exe-file in python directory (which already in PATH)

Comment: once i added C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox to my system path and put the geckodriver.exe file in that folder all worked well (windows 10.1) 
(im pretty sure im not supposed to put the exact path though)

Answer (score 1):

export path works only in the terminal you have entered the command. If you try to run the script from a different terminal, you will get the same error.