# How to put geckodriver into PATH?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm on OS Sierra and i'm running Python 3.5.2. I have selenium installed and i'm following a book called "Automate the Boring Tasks With Python"

My code is

```
from selenium import webdriver
>>> browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

I keep receiving the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 64, in start
stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'geckodriver'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 135, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 71, in start
os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

I have searched far and wide for solutions to my issue. Many people have the same issue.. but none of the solutions are working. I have geckodriver copied everywhere in my Python folders. I've tried using terminal and I have tried specifying the path within the code and it still gives me errors. I hope somebody can help me. I'm sorry if this is in the wrong format, I don't know what i'm doing.

Comment: What version of `Firefox` are you using?

Comment: I am using Firefox 49.0.2

Comment: You just need to set only directory where executable geckodriver exists in the PATH variable instead of executable geckodriver itself in the PATH. Thanks

Comment: @SaurabhGaur I have seen that exact same question and that's the same issue i'm having. However none of the answers have worked for me.

Answer (score 18):

I faced this same problem and here's how I fixed it:

1. Download the `geckodriver` from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)
2. Extract and unzip and move the `geckodriver` file to `/usr/local/bin/` directory
3. Run python program with selenium `Firefox` webdriver.

Comment: I have done this and i'm still getting the same issue.

Comment: What are the file permissions on your `geckodriver` file?

Comment: It's set to read and write for everyone. I also have my security set to open apps downloaded from anywhere.

Comment: @MatthewGarcia cool. It needs to be an executable else it will never run. Can you run `chmod ugo+x geckodriver` please?

Comment: @MatthewGarcia still the same error?

Answer (score 5):

You will need to add the binary to your `$PATH`.  You can do this by:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/geckodriver
```

Answer (score 2):

"I have geckodriver copied everywhere in my Python folders."
Ensure the geckodriver executable is found in one of the paths when you run:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

And the problem should be resolved.