# web scraping w/age verification

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Hello I want to web scrape data from a site with an age verification pop-up using python 3.x and beautifulsoup. I can't get to the underlying text and images without clicking "yes" for "are you over 21". Thanks for any support.

EDIT: Thanks, with some help from a comment I see that I can use the cookies but am not sure how to manage/store/call cookies with the requests package.

So with some help from another user I am using selenium package so that it will work also in case it's a graphical overlay (I think?). Having trouble getting it to work with the gecko driver but will keep trying! Thanks for all the advice again, everyone.

EDIT 3: OK I have made progress and I can get the browser window to open, using the gecko driver!~ Unfortunately it doesn't like that link specification so I'm posting again. The link to click "yes" on the age verification is buried on that page as something called mlink...

EDIT 4: Made some progress, updated code is below. I managed to find the element in the XML code, now I just need to manage to click the link.

```
#
import time
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'/Users/jeff/Documents/geckodriver') # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.get('https://www.shopharborside.com/oakland/#/shop/412');

url = 'https://www.shopharborside.com/oakland/#/shop/412'
driver.get(url)

#
driver.find_element_by_class_name('hhc_modal-body').click(Yes)

#wait.1.second
time.sleep(1)

pagesource = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(pagesource)

#you.can.now.enjoy.soup
print(soup.prettify())
```

Edit new: Stuck again, here is the current code. I seem to have isolated the element "mBtnYes" but I get an error when running the code : 
**ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element  is not clickable at point (625,278.5500030517578) because another element  obscures it**

```
 import time
 import selenium
 from selenium import webdriver
 from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
 from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'/Users/jeff/Documents/geckodriver') # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
 driver.get('https://www.shopharborside.com/oakland/#/shop/412');

 url = 'https://www.shopharborside.com/oakland/#/shop/412'
 driver.get(url)

 #

 driver.find_element_by_id('myBtnYes').click()

 #wait.1.second
 time.sleep(1)

 pagesource = driver.page_source
 soup = BeautifulSoup(pagesource)

 #you.can.now.enjoy.soup
 print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: So... You would need to click that button using Python, then. Find the form responsible for that, specify the parameters and send it!

Comment: You can use this cookie `document.cookie = "ageConfirmation=true;";` **ageConfirmation=true** in your request since the website is checking it in order to show age confirmation check

Answer (score 1):

if your aim is to click the verification get to selenium:
ps install selenium && get geckodriver(firefox) or chromedriver(chrome)

```
#Mossein~King(hi i'm here to help)
import time
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

#this.is.for.headless.This.will.save.you.a.bunch.of.research.time(Trust.me)
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options)

#for.graphical(you.need.gecko.driver.for.firefox)
# driver = webdriver.Firefox()

url = 'your-url'
driver.get(url)

#get.the.link.to.clicking
#exaple if<a class='MosseinKing'>
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='MosseinKing']").click()

#wait.1.secong.in.case.of.transitions
time.sleep(1)

pagesource = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(pagesource)

#you.can.now.enjoy.soup
print soup.prettify()
```

Comment: managed to install selenium. Firefox is fine, but having trouble with the gecko driver stuff.  I seem to have the driver but not sure how to call it in the code... running mac os sierra. what about chrome? any other tips?

Comment: Just add the geckodriver in your [**PATH**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40388503/how-to-put-geckodriver-into-path). Check the link.

Comment: Hi thanks, I made progress, and found the element, now I need to get it to click. see the above code which has been edited