# Pycharm Selenium Geckodriver Path issue

Tags: python, selenium

I already tried the solutions found in another posts without any success.

Every time I have tried to use python with selenium WebDrive in pycharm I get the same error, error log:

> "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver'
>   executable needs to be in PATH. I already downloaded the Geckodriver
>   exe file and added the link to systems variables but the message
>   didn't change.

Thank you

Comment: You can check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40388503/how-to-put-geckodriver-into-path/40392714

Answer (score 0):

I have used Selenium with python on Ubuntu Linux.
For selenium i have been working with chrome driver.
Following code i am using for a long time.

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=%s" % WINDOW_SIZE)
chrome_options.binary_location = CHROME_PATH
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="ChromDriver/chromedriver",chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Here *`chrome_options.binary_location = CHROME_PATH`* is the location of chrome binary path where it is located after installation of google chrome. In my case it was *`/usr/bin/google-chrome`*
Moreover *`executable_path="ChromDriver/chromedriver"`* is the location of chromediver for selenium which is placed inside ChromDriver directory with source code.